# Unable to see 6Ghz wireless networks on Ubuntu live

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager, asus, mediatek

To start I am running a Asus ProArt Creative motherboard and Ubuntu 23.04, the appropriate lshw info for the wireless interface is:

```
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: MT7922 802.11ax PCI Express Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       logical name: wlp9s0
       version: 00
       serial: d8:80:83:82:32:d5
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=mt7921e driverversion=6.2.0-20-generic firmware=____000000-20221227123243 ip=192.168.50.86 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: iomemory:f80-f7f irq:179 memory:f875300000-f8753fffff memory:ebe00000-ebe07fff
```

The lower network frequencies seem fine however I am not seeing my 6Ghz network. The router is an Asus ROG  Rapture GT-AXE16000 and it has the 4 networks separate, each with a different name. I can see the other three networks but the 6Ghz one is missing. I've tried searching but it appears a bad intel wireless card has really flooded the search results.

I would like to confirm the 6Ghz band is usable before running the installer if possible (I currently have Debian installed on the internal drive but it too is unable to see the network). I saw that Ubuntu 22.04 works according to the [linux-hardware](https://linux-hardware.org/?id=pci:14c3-0616-105b-e0cd) page so I was hoping that it would "just work" when I booted up the live USB.

Unfortunately I don't have another 6Ghz device to test with but nothing in the router is giving me any indication that there is a problem there, I can provide logs if requested.

**Additional Information**

`iwlist freq`

```
wlp9s0    32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
          Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
          Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz
          Channel 140 : 5.7 GHz
          Channel 144 : 5.72 GHz
          Channel 149 : 5.745 GHz
          Current Frequency:5.5 GHz (Channel 100)
```

and `sudo dmesg | grep frim`

```
[    0.127849] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    4.274324] [drm] Loading DMUB firmware via PSP: version=0x07000A01
[    4.274649] [drm] Found VCN firmware Version ENC: 1.9 DEC: 5 VEP: 0 Revision: 1
[    4.274653] amdgpu 0000:03:00.0: amdgpu: Will use PSP to load VCN firmware
[    4.821392] [drm] Loading DMUB firmware via PSP: version=0x05000500
[    4.821996] [drm] Found VCN firmware Version ENC: 1.24 DEC: 2 VEP: 0 Revision: 0
[    4.821999] amdgpu 0000:6d:00.0: amdgpu: Will use PSP to load VCN firmware
```

For whatever reason the 6Ghz network is occasionally showing however I can't connect to it.

`sudo dmesg | grep mt79`

```
[    9.924462] mt7921e 0000:09:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    9.958278] mt7921e 0000:09:00.0: ASIC revision: 79220010
[   10.048367] mt7921e 0000:09:00.0: HW/SW Version: 0x8a108a10, Build Time: 20221227123154a
[   10.069659] mt7921e 0000:09:00.0: WM Firmware Version: ____000000, Build Time: 20221227123243
[   11.166205] mt7921e 0000:09:00.0 wlp9s0: renamed from wlan0
```

and `sudo iw reg get`

```
global
country US: DFS-FCC
    (902 - 904 @ 2), (N/A, 30), (N/A)
    (904 - 920 @ 16), (N/A, 30), (N/A)
    (920 - 928 @ 8), (N/A, 30), (N/A)
    (2400 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 30), (N/A)
    (5150 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 23), (N/A), AUTO-BW
    (5250 - 5350 @ 80), (N/A, 24), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW
    (5470 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 24), (0 ms), DFS
    (5730 - 5850 @ 80), (N/A, 30), (N/A), AUTO-BW
    (5850 - 5895 @ 40), (N/A, 27), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5925 - 7125 @ 320), (N/A, 12), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 71000 @ 2160), (N/A, 40), (N/A)
```

Comment: What does this tell us? `iwlist freq` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Also, check here and tell us which firmware is loading: `sudo dmesg | grep firm` Possibly helpful: https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-wireless/msg231017.html

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: I updated the original post with the output from those two commands.

Comment: Let's dig deeper: `sudo dmesg | grep mt79` and also: `sudo iw reg get`

Comment: That's for the help with this @chili555. I've been looking for possibly solutions and the best I've come up with is to change the sensitivity of the wireless but I don't want to do that unless I can get the current sensitivity to roll back to.

Comment: "(5925 - 7125 @ 320), (N/A, 12), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, PASSIVE-SCAN" Good news! Are the 6 gHz channels seen here? `nmcli device wifi list` Please explain 'sensitivity'.

Comment: I see my 6Ghz network there however it appears to not have a channel and the rate is only 61Mbit/s when the other networks from the same router are 540/Mbit/s and all have a channel.

As for sensitivity it's the work used in this post about a similar wireless here: https://www.reddit.com/r/GamingLaptops/comments/pbbdcv/mediatek_mt7921_wifi_6_issues_used_in_most_2021/ presumably meaning how bad the connection quality can be before it gives up.

Comment: Is the router set to auto channel select or a fixed channel? Generally, at least in Ubuntu, a fixed channel is preferred.

Comment: Yes it was set to automatic. I set it to use a fixed channel (37, which is what is was set to at that moment) but when I try to connect it still just times out and gives up and `nmcli device wifi list` still shows channel 0.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145593/discussion-between-chili555-and-phillip-gooch).

Comment: You posted info says you do not have a 6e  6Ghz router.

Comment: @David He absolutely does have a 6 gHz router; see chat.